# Unable to build ASP.Net apps

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-4.8

I am trying to build and compile an ASP.Net solution. The solution is new. Here is how I create it:
[image]

[image]

[image: I had also tried to configure for HTTPS]

For this demonstration I avoid creating anything post-creating the project,
And here are the errors that I am getting:
[image]

All errors above, lead to the following place:
[image]

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Before you get too far down this path of creating a new .NET Framework based ASP.NET project in 2022 - are you sure you want to be doing that? For the most part, new development should be done in ASP.NET Core on a currently supported .NET version, .NET 6 at the moment. You may be spinning your wheels trying to solve a problem for a framework that you shouldn't be using.

Comment: Hi, Yes :) My manager asked me to get familiar with this, before proceeding to more relevant technologies.

Comment: Okay, perhaps they have some legacy apps. Fair enough. Sometimes Visual Studio gets in a weird state, and doing a Clean followed by a Build, or restarting Visual Studio can be of use. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, assuming you looking to create a asp.net webforms app?

Your screen caps look ok, and it not clear why your resulting application has errors, or build issues.

I would try to create another project, different name. See if that works.

Better, try tapping windows key, type in 2022, and then right click and try run as administrator, and see if that helps. (the default source folder might for some reason require elevated rights to work).

And if above does not work?

then I would try a repair, or even re-install of VS. Perhaps the templates are messed up.

Following your exact steps, my vs2022 created asp.net web applcation without issues.

best guess:

Your VS install is messed up, re-install, or repair.

tools->get tools and features.

Then: close the modifying window, and you should see this:

[image]

Try a repair.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Albert and everyone attempting to help!

What I did that solved the issue is to click the errors, and I was redirected to the following document:
[image]

Here, I deleted every tag that was highlighted in any of the errors, more specifically, things related to Video Builder Cloud Services (VBCS), and off I go :)
[image]

Comment: That's not a good solution. And that's not Video Builder Cloud Services. It probably stands for Visual Basic/C Sharp (C#) Compiler. Deleting it might break things in unexpected ways, and you may not realize it until much later. I highly recommend you undo whatever you did and instead try the troubleshooting steps I posted in the comment on your question, and if that doesn't resolve it then try the repair steps that Albert's answer mentioned.